# Android GPS and Network Provider

Tags: android, gps, updates

Is it necessary for gps to be enabled while getting location updates through Network_provider like:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,listener);
```

while GPS of android device is disabled . . . ? ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no , you just have to be connected through wi-fi or any network means. you have separate provider string for GPS e.g `locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, listener);`